# RestTemplate vs WebClient benefits in Servlet based web-mvc app

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflux

I'm looking for a clarification on the bolded text in the statement below (I've provided the full paragraph for context only):

> The RestTemplate is not a good fit for use in non-blocking applications, and therefore Spring WebFlux application should always use the WebClient. **The WebClient should also be preferred in Spring MVC**, in most high concurrency scenarios, and for composing a sequence of remote, inter-dependent calls.

Found here: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html

In particular what is the benefit of using `WebClient` over `RestTemplate` for Spring MVC apps? How would `WebClient` achieve higher scale vs say `RestTemplate` configured with apache `HttpClient` and `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager` with suitably configured connection and socket configuration?

Answer (score 14):

`WebClient` is non-blocking, while `RestTemplate` is blocking/synchronous. If you're using the non-blocking WebFlux API with a blocking library, you're essentially turning it into a blocking API.

Think of `RestTemplate` as actually creating a new **Thread** for each event, vs `WebClient` creating a **Task** (as if on a *queue*, which is essentially what Reactor manages for you behind the covers). 
You'll soon reach **Thread** starvation if for every non-blocking task you have a blocking call backing it (as would be the case for each `RestTemplate`; note that delegating to the `ConnectionManager` is still making blocking call). 
On the other hand a **Task** will get *queued* up by the reactive framework and get executed when you have the appropriate resources available.

**Why use WebClient with Spring MVC**

WebClient is non-blocking! You can use all of the `Flux` features with it (pub-sub, backpressure, etc.). This helps conserve resources (i.e. you use less threads and less memory), and Reactor will allow you to maximize the use of threads you're not using.
The question here isn't really "why should I use WebClient" with Spring MVC, the question is, "why should I use a reactive/non-blocking" framework with my application. Lots of examples ([here's one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42062199/reactive-programming-advantages-disadvantages)) on the internet of this question and it's answers.

`Mono` and `Flux` can also return a [Java 8 `CompletableFuture`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#toFuture--) if you want to use a non-reactive non-blocking construct.

**Why use WebClient with WebFlux**

See this quote from the page you [referenced in that documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html):

> **WebClient** uses the same codecs as **WebFlux** server applications do, and
>   shares a common base package, some common APIs, and infrastructure
>   with the server functional web framework. The API exposes Reactor **Flux**
>   and **Mono** types

The key point there is that `WebClient` uses the same reactive non-blocking types as does `Flux`. That's why the integrate so nicely and you get the nice tasking feature. For example (and I'm borrowing a chunk of code from [that doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html)):

```
WebClient client = WebClient.create("http://example.org");
Mono<Void> result = client.post()
        .uri("/persons/{id}", id)
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .body(personMono, Person.class)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(Void.class);
```

See how that piece of code yields a `Mono`? That's a reactive construct the `WebFlux` is *built on* and that's why you'd use it with the framework. For example, you can actually [return that `Mono` reactively in a `Controller` call](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/html/web-reactive.html#web-reactive-server-annotation):

```
@PostMapping("/person")
Mono<Void> create(@RequestBody Publisher<Person> personStream) {
     // ... above code could go here...
     return result; 
}
```

This type of thing is the key reason why they say you should use `WebClient` with the `WebFlux` library.

Comment: I actually knew all that, but my question resolves around why they suggest you use WebClient with Spring Web MVC, which is the older blocking/thread-per-request framework. Is there some benefit to WebClient in that context that I'm not aware of?

Comment: I've updated my question above, the bolded text in the quoted snippet is the only thing I need clarification on, I already understand blocking vs non-blocking and why WebClient should be used with WebFlux. @Dovmo

Comment: Hope that clarifies things!

Comment: See https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/html/web-reactive.html#web-reactive-server, in particular note that the `@Controller` annotation sits on top of both web-mvc and webflux. Web-mvc runs on top of a container implementing the servlet spec. Your examples are still 100% webflux and my question relates to use cases for WebClient with spring webmvc.

Comment: Hope that clarifies things some more!

Answer (score 4):

After a bit of research, I believe the answer lies in Spring's [DeferredResult](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/async/DeferredResult.html). To steal a bit of verbiage from this [blog](https://www.nurkiewicz.com/2013/03/deferredresult-asynchronous-processing.html),

> DeferredResult is a container for possibly not-yet-finished computation that will be available in future. Spring MVC uses it to represent asynchronous computation and take advantage of Servlet 3.0 AsyncContext asynchronous request handling.

I believe what happened was prior to WebFlux, this DeferredResult concept was a first cut at supporting asynchronous IO inside of Spring MVC, for example there is also a now deprecated [AsyncRestTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/AsyncRestTemplate.html) which returns `ListenableFuture` wrappers.

So this means that if I have a relatively simple REST API with spring MVC, I could potentially return a `DeferredFuture` that generates its result asynchronously via `WebClient`, and thus gain some of the benefits of asynchronous processing without having to migrate away from Spring MVC (which may be infeasible for some projects).