# Can I use a standalone WebClient without Webflux

Tags: spring, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I'm developing a reactive service and preparing to use the [WebClient](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webflux/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.java) to exchange with HTTP APIs,but the service is not in a reactive web stack so how can I use it(WebClient) without depending on Webflux or is there any alternative reactive HTTP client?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I get your question correct: You want to use an inherently reactive class without the reactive lib in which it is contained?

As you can see via the link you put in your question, the `WebClient` is part of `spring-webflux` and depends e.g. on `reactor.core.publisher.Mono` which resides in `compile("io.projectreactor:reactor-core")`. I can not imagine any scenario in which this `WebClient` would work or make any sense as you've asked "without depending on Webflux".

Other reactive HTTP clients are:

- [RxHttpClient](https://github.com/WegenenVerkeer/RxHttpClient)
- [Java HTTP Client introduced in Java 11](https://openjdk.java.net/groups/net/httpclient/intro.html)

May be you could elaborate a little bit more on your needs, why you won't rely on `WebFlux` or why you want to use a reactive client in a non-reactive stack.

Comment: You can use Spring Reactor in Spring MVC applications. You can return Mono and Flux from Spring MVC Controllers and they resolve asynchronously.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-programming-models and https://stackoverflow.com/a/51955755/855893 You might not have the full gains, but it is not that it makes not sense at all.

Comment: Because the Spring team has gone golden-hammer on reactive and refuses to support basic operations such as OAuth2 requests in RestTemplate.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- they provide OAuth2 support for the both system webclient and resttemplate
See https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/OAuth2RestTemplate.html