# Spring webclient in a Servlet context

Tags: spring-boot, servlets, webclient, reactive

In the Spring documentation, you can use WebClient in A Servlet application. But is it still really a non blocking client with a tomcat server ?

Or in a servlet application ther is no benefits to use webclient instead of RestClient, openFeign ... ?

I've read the doc. it's not clear.

Thanks

Comment: The `WebClient` is still non blocking (why wouldn't it). Tomcat obviously wouldn't be, the your client would be.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RestTemplate vs WebClient benefits in Servlet based web-mvc app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51953826/resttemplate-vs-webclient-benefits-in-servlet-based-web-mvc-app)